# how to get a string by using substring?

Tags: c#, iis-and-asp.net

my following string

```
<Content xmlns="http://www.kkk.com/HTMLMeta">
    <title>Aftersales Marketing Solutions | kkk markit</title>
    <metaDescription>Helps manage key touchpoints during the vehicle ownership life cycle to increase revenue and improve customer loyalty.</metaDescription>
    <primaryKeywords>
        <solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>Products and Solutions</solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>
        <rank>6</rank>
        <productKeyword>Aftersales Marketing Solutions</productKeyword>
        <businessLine>Automotive</businessLine>
        <primaryIndustry>Banking</primaryIndustry>
        <subIndustry>Coal</subIndustry>
        <rollup>Technology</rollup>
        <secondaryIndustries>Chemicals</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Aerospace, Defense &amp; Security</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Electronics</secondaryIndustries>
        <pageTypeKeyword>Solution Page</pageTypeKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Audience Targeting</topicKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Retail performance</topicKeyword>
        <regionKeyword>Global</regionKeyword>
    </primaryKeywords>
    <dynamicTag>Multiview</dynamicTag>
    <boostDetails>
        <industryValue>Automotive</industryValue>
        <boostValue>-10</boostValue>
    </boostDetails>
</Content>
```

**string 1 to get the string as**

```
<Content xmlns="http://www.kkk.com/HTMLMeta">
    <title>Aftersales Marketing Solutions | kkk markit</title>
    <metaDescription>Helps manage key touchpoints during the vehicle ownership life cycle to increase revenue and improve customer loyalty.</metaDescription>
    <primaryKeywords>
        <solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>Products and Solutions</solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>
        <rank>6</rank>
        <productKeyword>Aftersales Marketing Solutions</productKeyword>
        <businessLine>Automotive</businessLine>
        <primaryIndustry>Banking</primaryIndustry>
```

**string 2** `<subIndustry>Coal</subIndustry>`

**string 3** `<rollup>Technology</rollup>`

**string 4**

```
    <secondaryIndustries>Chemicals</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Aerospace, Defense &amp; Security</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Electronics</secondaryIndustries>
        <pageTypeKeyword>Solution Page</pageTypeKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Audience Targeting</topicKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Retail performance</topicKeyword>
        <regionKeyword>Global</regionKeyword>
    </primaryKeywords>
    <dynamicTag>Multiview</dynamicTag>
    <boostDetails>
        <industryValue>Automotive</industryValue>
        <boostValue>-10</boostValue>
    </boostDetails>
</Content>
```

how to split as following string as string 1, string 2 ,string 3 n string 4?

Comment: This isn't really a tridion-specific question, so I don't think it belongs here. You may ask it in a more appropriate Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, the simple answer would be: you don't split the XML into strings. You parse it as XML and extract the data that you want.

So, for instance, here's some Powershell code that reads the `subIndustry` and `rollup` values:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<Content xmlns="http://www.kkk.com/HTMLMeta">
    <title>Aftersales Marketing Solutions | kkk markit</title>
    <metaDescription>Helps manage key touchpoints during the vehicle ownership life cycle to increase revenue and improve customer loyalty.</metaDescription>
    <primaryKeywords>
        <solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>Products and Solutions</solrPrimaryNavigatorKeyword>
        <rank>6</rank>
        <productKeyword>Aftersales Marketing Solutions</productKeyword>
        <businessLine>Automotive</businessLine>
        <primaryIndustry>Banking</primaryIndustry>
        <subIndustry>Coal</subIndustry>
        <rollup>Technology</rollup>
        <secondaryIndustries>Chemicals</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Aerospace, Defense &amp; Security</secondaryIndustries>
        <secondaryIndustries>Electronics</secondaryIndustries>
        <pageTypeKeyword>Solution Page</pageTypeKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Audience Targeting</topicKeyword>
        <topicKeyword>Retail performance</topicKeyword>
        <regionKeyword>Global</regionKeyword>
    </primaryKeywords>
    <dynamicTag>Multiview</dynamicTag>
    <boostDetails>
        <industryValue>Automotive</industryValue>
        <boostValue>-10</boostValue>
    </boostDetails>
</Content>
@"

$subIndustries = $xml.Content.primaryKeywords.subIndustry;
$rollup = $xml.Content.primaryKeywords.rollup
```